# C programming error when i redirect the output of a c file to another file

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I currently have a file named assign1.c that compiles and runs correctly when I run it using SSH to connect to a remote Linux terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141593

int main(){
    int degrees = 0;
    double radians;

    printf("Degrees to Radians \n");

    degrees = 0;
    radians = degrees*PI/180;
    printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);

    degrees = 10;
    radians = degrees*PI/180;
    printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);

    while( degrees < 350){
        degrees +=10;
        radians = degrees*PI/180;
        printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);
    }

    degrees = 360;
    radians = degrees*PI/180;
    printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);

}
```

I used ./assign1 > prog1.c to redirect and send the output to a different file prog1.c

```
Degrees to Radians 
     0  0.000000 
    10  0.174533 
    20  0.349066 
    30  0.523599 
    40  0.698132 
    50  0.872665 
    60  1.047198 
    70  1.221731 
    80  1.396264 
    90  1.570796 
   100  1.745329 
   110  1.919862 
   120  2.094395 
   130  2.268928 
   140  2.443461 
   150  2.617994 
   160  2.792527 
   170  2.967060 
   180  3.141593 
   190  3.316126 
   200  3.490659 
   210  3.665192 
   220  3.839725 
   230  4.014258 
   240  4.188791 
   250  4.363324 
   260  4.537857 
   270  4.712389 
   280  4.886922 
   290  5.061455 
   300  5.235988 
   310  5.410521 
   320  5.585054 
   330  5.759587 
   340  5.934120 
   350  6.108653 
   360  6.283186
```

However when I try to compile gcc -o prog1 prog1.c I recieve an error message.

```
prog1.c:1:1: error: unknown type name âDegreesâ
 Degrees to Radians 
 ^
prog1.c:1:12: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âRadiansâ
 Degrees to Radians 
            ^
```

I am new to C programming and still having problems understanding the error messages, any one actually understand my error message?

Comment: When you redirect it to the source file you *overwrite* the original source file with the output of the first program. You probably meant to *pipe* the output from the first program to the second (compiled) program instead, like `./assign1  | ./prog1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused on what you are trying to achieve, so i'll tell you the full story.

So, you have a program, written in C (i.e. a text file). Since the computer doesn't understand text, we need to translate it in a computer language. So, you have the program assign1.c, you compile that in a executable file (i.e. translate C into a machine-readable form):

```
gcc -o assign1 assign1.c
```

Then, you run assign1:

```
./assign1
```

, which produces a bunch of output on the stdout (i.e. on the screen). You can write that into a file using a redirection:

```
./assign1 > prog1.c
```

Now, the file prog1.c is a simple text file which contains the output produced by your program (the extension is irrelevant). Trying to compile that using gcc is useless, because it is not a valid C program, but rather, it contains the output from your program.

Now, what to do with this file? Well, whatever you want. You can take a look at it:

cat prog1.c

or

less prog1.c

(q to quit from less), or send it to a friend or...whatever.